# Use export buttons on DataTable

Tags: laravel, datatables, export-to-csv

I have a DataTable that has server-side processing using Ajax. I am trying to add export buttons to it, but I haven't been successful. I am extending a Laravel view that has all the files in it already, but I am unable to get the buttons to show.

Master page with necessary files:

```
    <!-- Datatable -->
    <link  href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/buttons.html5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.0/js/dataTables.select.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/buttons.flash.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Page with DataTable:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#payments-table').DataTable({
                  dom: 'Bfrtip',
                  buttons: [
                      'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
                ],
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                ajax: '{{ route('get.payments') }}',
                order:[ [5,'desc'] ],
                columns: [

                    { data: 'id', name: 'id' },
                    { data: 'sub_id', name: 'sub_id' },
                    { data: 'company_name', name: 'company_name'},
                    { data: 'amount', name: 'amount'},
                    { data: 'status', name: 'status'},
                    { data: 'job_date', name: 'job_date'},
                    { data: 'amount_payed', name: 'amount_payed'},
                    { data: 'date_payed', name: 'date_payed'},
                    { data: 'trn_ss', name: 'trn_ss'},
                    { data: 'account_number', name: 'account_number'},
                    { data: 'bank_name', name: 'bank_name'},
                    { data: 'bank_branch', name: 'bank_branch'},
              ]
            });
  });
```

The DataTable displays correctly, but the buttons don't display, and I don't know what it could be.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to manually put the buttons in?

```
var table = $('#payments-table').DataTable({...

$('#div_to_place_buttons_in').html(table.buttons().container());
```

From my experience with DataTables you won't need the `dom: 'Bfrtip'` if you manually move the buttons container to a different place.

For your comment just change your DataTables instantiation to be held in a variable called table and remove the `dom` part, and then you will have access to the instance of DataTables in the table variable. See below:

```
var table = $('#payments-table').DataTable({
            buttons: [
                'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
            ],
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: '{{ route('get.payments') }}',
            order:[ [5,'desc'] ],
            columns: [

                { data: 'id', name: 'id' },
                { data: 'sub_id', name: 'sub_id' },
                { data: 'company_name', name: 'company_name'},
                { data: 'amount', name: 'amount'},
                { data: 'status', name: 'status'},
                { data: 'job_date', name: 'job_date'},
                { data: 'amount_payed', name: 'amount_payed'},
                { data: 'date_payed', name: 'date_payed'},
                { data: 'trn_ss', name: 'trn_ss'},
                { data: 'account_number', name: 'account_number'},
                { data: 'bank_name', name: 'bank_name'},
                { data: 'bank_branch', name: 'bank_branch'},
          ]
        });
$('#div_to_place_buttons_in').html(table.buttons().container());
```

I'm not sure what your HTML looks like, but you just need a div/similar container to place the buttons in and reference it instead of `div_to_place_buttons_in`.

Comment: I've never tried this, this is my first timw working with them. I will give it a try

Comment: Could you provide some more info on how to go about doing this?

Comment: thank you. I did just that but the buttons still don't appear

Comment: Is the console showing any errors or are you getting any errors on the network tab when it pulls in the package?

Comment: Yes i am  seeing some erros saying JQuery is undefined. I am using Laravela dn extending a layout with the necessary scripts. I will show you

Comment: @N. Mahurin Its saying tables.buttons is not a function in console

Comment: If jquery is showing as undefined and tables.buttons is not a function then the problem is likely with how you are pulling in your scripts. Make sure you pull in jquery first, then ajax, then your datatables.js file, and then pull in the buttons.js.